# Why Tomcat's LifyCycleSupport.java use array to store listeners instead of any advanced containers(ArrayList)?

Tags: java, arrays, apache, tomcat, catalina

Im recently going through tomcat's source code, I found that in the LifecycleSupport.java class, it stores Listeners by simple arrays,

```
private LifecycleListener listeners[] = new LifecycleListener[0];
```

so the add() method has to create a new array to replace the old one:

```
public void addLifecycleListener(LifecycleListener listener) {
   82   
   83         synchronized (listenersLock) {
   84             LifecycleListener results[] =
   85               new LifecycleListener[listeners.length + 1];
   86             for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++)
   87                 results[i] = listeners[i];
   88             results[listeners.length] = listener;
   89             listeners = results;
   90         }
   91   
   92       }
```

I wonder whats the purpose to use array instead of advanced java containers like ArrayList, since its much more convenient to perform add/remove action?

Thanks

Comment: Because that's all she wrote. Purely opinion-based here, unless you happen to get the developer on the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me they have to provide ***backward compatibility*** to old versions of java so that old jre/jdk feel comfortable with Tomcat.Otherwise there is no other reason to use array but one more thing to note `ArrayList` internally manipulates array so no improvement what so ever.But kindly note it's obvious `array[index]` is faster than `array.get(index)`.

Comment: How exactly would this measure promote backward compatibility? If you're claiming that Tomcat is mandated to run on Java 1.1, please provide a reference.

Comment: Thanks, EJP, I just read a book named How Tomcat Works, it mentions about using arrays instead of Strings to make the programme faster. Does anyone test arrays agains ArrayList in certain web environment?